# How can I check if a character of a string is already a element of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, comparison, counter

With a string, ex: `data`. I want to insert all new characters in an array, respecting the example I gave the answer should be:

```
characters = ["d","a","t"];
```

I did the following up to now:

```
const balanced = string => {
  var characters = [];
  var characters_Counter = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string.charAt(i) != characters){
      characters[characters_Counter] = string.charAt(i);
      characters_Counter++;
    }
    
    console.log(characters[i]);
  }
  
};
```

In the `if` I want to compare `string.charAt(i)` with all the elements inside `characters[]` and if it is a new character do the `if`'s content. The problem is: I'm stuck, I can't think a way to make this comparison work.

Comment: Please define valid input/output also as we can understand what exactly you are wanting.

Comment: Have you looked at the Array `.includes()` method? It does exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ... or you can just populate all items and then strip duplicates with `[...new Set(array)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check if an element (character) is inside an array

```js
const balanced = string => {
  var characters = [];
  var characters_Counter = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!characters.includes(string.charAt(i))) {    // <------ here
      characters[characters_Counter] = string.charAt(i);
      characters_Counter++;
      console.log(characters[i]);
    }
  }

};

balanced("data");
```